# What I can use for graphics debugging/profiling in old applications?

Tags: 3d, pixel-graphics, profiling, opengl, nvidia

What software I can use for debugging graphics/GPU profiling in old applications? (for example, apps which based on D3D8 or using OpenGL Immediate Mode)

All modern solutions which I checked, like RenderDoc or Nsight, isn't compatible with old graphic libraries.
Maybe exists some solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

So, I found out that [apitrace](http://apitrace.github.io/) can be partially used for similar tasks. At least, at this time this soft makes available to trace graphics API calls and show viewports content in D3D8 applications.